# JScrollpane not scrolling big content

Tags: java, swing, size, jscrollpane

I have this simple example where I want to display a large panel in a small frame.
Java documentation tell the scrollpane will automatically fit its contents in its viewport and add scrollbars.
However I have no such luck. No scrollpane nor its content appear.
Here is what I have tried.

```
public class MyWindow extends JFrame {
    JPanel panel;
    JScrollPane scroll;

    public MyWindow(){  
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setSize(1000,1000);
        scroll = new JScrollPane(panel);

        add(scroll,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setSize(300, 300);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

As stated in similar questions,

1. I made the panel bigger than frame.
2. I added border layout to frame.

Still no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `JScrollPane` is free to disregard the initial size of the panel. You need to set the preferred size

```
panel = new JPanel() {
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(1000, 1000);
    };
};
```

Comment: Weird ! Thank you. I wasted a day for this.

Comment: @user3041058, this will solve the problem for the simple code you posted. `. Java documentation tell the scrollpane will automatically fit its contents in its viewport and add scrollbars` - but in a real application you should be using a layout manager and the layout manager will determine the preferred size of the panel based on the rules of the layout manager and the preferred size of the components you add to the panel. Unless you are creating a custom component you really should not override the getPreferredSize() method. Let the layout manager to its job.